Car shakes and vibrates when braking
I have a 2018 Volvo S90 that has a vibrating problem when braking. I’ve had the brakes and rotors replaced 4 times in the last 4 years. The first 3 times it was covered and replaced at the dealer. This last time my mechanic replaced them. This was about 8 months ago less than 5000 miles. Now it’s happening again. There has to be more to this. This can’t be normal. What would be causing the wear like this?

Rotors aren't supposed to warp that quickly; worse yet, it's just a symptom of a larger issue. You are either braking too hard, the calipers are sticking, or you have an upstream blockage in your brake lines. The fact that the dealer replaced them 3 times without fixing the larger issue is on par for what I'd expect from a dealer doing warranty work. The fact that your mechanic didn't suggest a proper fix (assuming you told them about the prior replacements) is indicative of their honesty.

Since it goes away (albeit temporarily) when you replace the pads/rotors it sounds as though whatever the problem is it's something that is damaging them and it is then the damage that is causing the vibration.
Two things come to mind here - either glazing of the pad surface or warping of the rotors.
The first is usually a result of excess heat and can cause a vibration, you'd also likely experience decrease in brake performance and the associate increase in stopping distances, (potentially even an episode of "brake fade" at the time the glazing happens if it's a sudden event rather than over time) and you may get a squeaking or squealing sound under light braking.
Assuming you aren't regularly tracking the car, otherwise working the brakes extremely hard for sustained periods, or riding the brakes then there's probably an underlying mechanical problem - such as a sticky calliper that's causing the pads to rub against the disc and overheat. If it were "just" glazed pads I'd be surprised at the need for disc replacement too as, assuming they aren't heavily worn you can just replace the pads and go about your day.
As for warped rotors this can be caused by the same things that would glaze a pad, and also, in a way, the opposite - most common for that is the rotors cooling unevenly - when one portion of the disc cools at a slower rate than the rest it can cause them to warp slightly which will give you that unpleasant  vibration and the need to replace both discs and pads. This can happen if you're holding the footbrake on when stationary (and the brakes are hot from regular but reasonably intensive use) as this can lead to one portion of the disc being trapped between hot brake pads (so it stays hot) and the rest exposed and the rest exposed and able to cool down much faster - in that case it isn't so much a mechanical issue as it is a driving one - instilling a habit of coming off the brakes once stationary and using the handbrake instead to hold the car can be a significant help here.
In your position I'd be looking into ensuring the callipers are all in correct working order - you can check a few things yourself easily if one side is sticking you may be able to detect a slight "pull" in one direction when not actually and that side will be appreciably hotter after driving for a while than the other, which would be detectable either with a suitable thermometer or subjectively by holding your hand near the brakes (don't touch them, that hurts!) or by getting a decent mechanic to inspect them. I'd also suggest it might be worth getting the brake fluid changed as if there has been any overheating moments it's possible for that to be damaged in the process.
That brings me to another possibility - I don't think it's hugely likely, but it's a possibility nonetheless, if there's an issue with the brake fluid system that's allowing ingress of air. This would give you vibrations as the air bubbles result in an uneven level of brake pressure. It would also go away (for a while) at a brake change because the mechanic would likely bleed the brakes as part of the change, but what wouldn't fit is that none of the mechanics who changed the brakes/pads noticed that they weren't worn.

+1 Excellent answer. I'd like to add that frequent driving in mountainous or hilly regions can lead to the above glazing and warping, and can me ameliorated by downshifting more often on long downhills to prevent overheating of brakes.

@MTA Definitely! particularly in a non-performance orientated car that's on the heavier side, which an S90 would count as. I've lived in a pretty hilly region previously myself and even driving a lighter, sporty car engine braking was a key skill or you risked brake fade or damage.
